# Architecture for a fast screener

Tags: sql, database, performance, filter

I'm building a screener that should be able to search through a table about 50 columns wide and 7000 rows long really fast.

Each row is composed of the following columns.

primary_key, quantity1, quantity2, quantity3...quantity50.

All quantities are essentially floats or integers. Hence a typical screener would look like this.

```
Get all rows which have quantity1 > x and quantity2 < y and quantity3 >= z.
```

Indexing all columns should lead to really fast search times however some of the columns will be updating in realtime. Indexing everything obviously leads to very low insert/update times.

A portion of the columns are fairly static though. Hence an idea was to segregate the data into two tables, one containing all columns that are static while the other containing data that is dynamic. Any screener would then be applied to both tables based on the actual query. And the results combined in the end.

I am currently planning on using a MySQL engine, most probably INNoDB. However I'm looking to get much faster response times. An implementation of the same problem on a certain site was very snappy. Regardless of the query size, I was getting the results within 500 ms. Wondering what other options are available out there to implement this function.

Comment: Personally I would use Solr for such task.

Comment: What is the frequency of inserts vs selects and the frequency of updates vs selects?

Also, in a typical query are you searching across all columns or a subset?

Comment: It'll only be updates. So the first frequency is essentially zero. Updates vs selects. Starting out, all records would be updated once every 5 minutes. Selects can be approximated to be 1 every minute. However this will scale as number of users on my site increase.

Comment: @fliespl Started using Solr. Its working like a charm. Thanks!